# iPad landscape single navigation bar

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, uisplitview

My app in iPad mode and landscape calls for a single navigation bar its proving troublesome.

The idea is that in landscape there wouldnt be 2 separate nav bars for Master and Detail : see below (Images taken from Google Images and modified, not my project)

[image]

but instead there would be a single nav bar, like so:

[image]

I'm trying to avoid very hackish methods because my navs use a lot of custom stylings but the only way I can think at the moment is to resize the view in the SplitView superclass and override the nav bar, but wanted to see if anyone else had any success before
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that the split view controller works, it displays two separate view controllers.  If you want to have the unified navigation bar, don't use a split view controller, just use a regular view controller, and embed the table view in your normal view, and implement the appropriate protocols to control the table

Comment: While I agree that would've been the way to go from the outset, at this stage I have several classes using a custom SplitView class with some nifty helper methods I'm way too chuffed with to throw away :)
Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: I'd say you could try wrapping the split view in a navigation controller, but iOS doesn't allow you to use a split view controller unless it is the root view controller